# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable error

Tags: python

I'm writing code to find the maximum sum of numbers in a list whose digits dont repeat and cant solve the error I'm getting.

```
def total(array,index,totalsofar,setsofar):
    if(index>=length):
        return 0
    else:
        movetonextelementflag=True
        i=0
        while(movetonextelementflag):
            flag=True
            if((index+i)<length):
                currentelementset=set(map(int, str(array[index+i])))
                for digit in currentelementset:
                    if(digit in setsofar):
                        flag=False
            if(flag):
                movetonextelementflag=False
                total1=totalsofar+total(array,index+1+i,totalsofar+array[index+i],setsofar.update(currentelementset))
                total2=totalsofar+total(array,index+2+i,totalsofar,setsofar)
                return max(total1,total2)
            i=i+1
    return -1


x=int(input())
for testcases in range(0,x):
    length=int(input())
    array=[]
    array = list(map(int,input().split()))
    emptyset=set()
    print(total(array,0,0,emptyset))
```

Comment: Where is the error trackback?

Answer (score 3):

One of elements in your list is `None`. It causes situation when value of `currentelementset` also equals `None`. When you're trying to iterate over `None` you get this error.

To prevent this error you should validate value you get from list before loop and handle situation if value is `None`.

```
currentelement = array[index+i]
if not currentelement:
    # do smth
currentelementset=set(map(int, str(currentelement))) # error is here
for digit in currentelementset:
    if(digit in setsofar):
        flag=False
```